# Unit Testing a class with a call to a Static class wrapping an HttpContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static-methods, httpcontext

I've got a method which I've added unit tests for in a C#/ASP.Net web project. The method has been modified by someone else to include a call to a static method on a class which wraps an HttpContext (to add some session state), but during testing I don't have an HttpContext, so this throws a null reference exception. Any ideas how to get round this problem? I don't want to make too many changes to production code if I can help it.

Method under test:

```
public int MethodUnderTest() 
{
    ...
    // Added line which breaks the tests
    StaticClass.ClearSessionState();
}
```

In StaticClass:

```
public void ClearSessionState()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["VariableName"] = null;
}
```

This throws a `NullReferenceException` because `HttpContext.Current` is null during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could just remove the call to `StaticClass.ClearSessionState()`, but thanks for all the answers. Useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much in a dead end here as far as unit testing methods that use `HttpContext.Current` are concerned. The proper way would be to modify this code to use constructor injection:

```
private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
public Foo(HttpContextBase context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public void ClearSessionState()
{
    _context.Session["VariableName"] = null;
}
```

Now you can mock this [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) in your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You could set HttpContext.Current with a mock/stub object before invoking the `StaticClass.ClearSessionState()` line.

Answer (score 1):

You could do your own static "injection" in the production code like so:

```
public static class StaticClass {
    public void ClearSession() {
        TheContext["VariableName"] = null;
    }

    public static HttpContextBase TheContext{
        get { 
            if (_context == null)
                _context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            return _context; }
        set { _context = value; }
    }
}
```

The actual test then becomes pretty trivial, simply set TheContext property to a stub instance before the test. For example in Moq such stub could be set up with one line:

```
StaticClass.TheContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(){DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock}.Object;
```